# function always return false before accessing the database in node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I´m making a RESTful api with node/express. And I´m having trouble with the  asynchronous part of javascript

For example, I have this:

```
function isWorkMine(workdata) {
    var result = false;
    Work.otherQueryToTheDB(workdata,(err,data) => {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            result = true;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

router.get("/works", (req, res) => {
    const workdata = {...}

    var result = isWorkMine(workdata);
    if (result) {
        Work.queryToTheDataBase(state,(err,data) => {
            if (data.length == 0) {
                return res.status(404);
            }
            res.json(data);
        }); 
    } else {
       console.log("Do Nothing!");
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that result is always false. I tried

```
async function isWorkMine(workdata) {
        var result = false;
        await Work.otherQueryToTheDB(workdata,(err,data) => {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                result = true;
            }
        });
        return result;
    };
```

But it didn´t work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can only `await` a promise. `Work.otherQueryToTheDB` accepts a callback and is not returning a promise.

Comment: You're using async function and expect them to be sync. Thats why, take a look at async / await. Or use proper Promises or Callbacks.